# Solution to $2u_{y}u_{yx} = 1 - e^{u}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving a partial differential equation, which has lead me to the equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(u^{2}_{y} \right) = 2u_{y}u_{yx} = 1 - e^{-u}$$

where $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. The goal is to solve for $u$.

My current tactic is to substitute $u = \log(w)$, so that I can kill the exponential on the right hand side

$$1 - e^{-u} = 1 - \frac{1}{w} = \frac{w - 1}{w}$$

For the left hand side, assuming I have done this correctly

\begin{align}
u_{y} &= \frac{\partial \log(w)}{\partial y} \\
&= \frac{w_{y}}{w} \\
u_{yx} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \log(w)}{\partial y} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{w_{y}}{w} \\
&= \frac{w_{yx}}{w} - \frac{w_{x}w_{y}}{w^2}
\end{align}

However, this leaves me with lots of nasty cross terms and the like. Is there a better way of proceeding?

```
 __________________________
```

EDIT: I am attempting to solve the equation for $f(x,y)$

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = 1 - e^{- \int \sqrt{f(x,y)} \ dy}$$

In order to remove the square root integral from the differential equation, I make the following substitution

$$\int \sqrt{f(x,y)} \ dy = u(x,y) \implies \sqrt{f} = u_y \implies f = u^{2}_{y}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u^{2}_{y} \right) = 2u_{y}u_{yx} = 1 - e^{-u}$$

Comment: What is the partial differential equation which has lead you to the cited equation. ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Full problem statement has been added.